# Truncate a string in Java after encountering a word that isn't uppercase or titlecase

Tags: java

I want to take only the words in a string that are uppercase or titlecase, stopping after getting to a word that is neither.

For example, `DOCTOR Foo Bar is not here` would become `DOCTOR Foo Bar` and `the NURSE Joy healed him` would return an empty string since the first word is neither uppercase nor titlecase.

I'd like to do something similar to this, but the code below doesn't work.

```
String name = text.split(" ").stream()
                    .takeWhile(w -> w.isUpperCase() || w.isTitleCase())
                    .collect(joining(" "));
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" in which way? Compiler Error, Exception, unexpected result?

Comment: it's easier if you use a for loop

Comment: `isTitleCase()` is not a method of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) - so is your question how to write an `isTitleCase`-check? (Same for `isUpperCase()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use matching criteria using the regex, `[A-Z][A-Za-z]*` which means the first letter as uppercase and the second onwards can be the upper or lower case but is optional (because of the quantifier, `*`).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "DOCTOR Foo Bar is not here", "the NURSE Joy healed him", "He And I are pronouns" };

        for (String text : arr) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s+")).takeWhile(w -> w.matches("[A-Z][A-Za-z]*"))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
DOCTOR Foo Bar

He And I
```

Note that I have used `\s+` as the splitting criteria to match one or more  whitespace between words.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to use `Arrays.stream()` to turn array into stream and you can check only the first letter of the word is uppercase or not for your condition.

```
String name = Arrays.stream(text.split(" "))
        .takeWhile(w -> Character.isUpperCase(w.charAt(0)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```

Comment: What's the difference between Array.stream(text.split(" ")) and text.split(" ").stream()?

Comment: @vincendep You can't use `.stream()` on array, you need to use `Array.stream` to turn arrays into the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it cannot work because it's not a Java code :) There are no `String::isUpperCase` or `String::isTitleCase` in Java

Anyway it would be something like

```
String name = Arrays.stream(text.split(" "))
                    .takeWhile(this::isUppercaseOrTitleCase)
                    .collect(joining(" "));

// and you need to write additional function
private boolean isUppercaseOrTitleCase(String string) {
    return string.equals(string.toUpperCase()) || Character.isUpperCase(string.charAt(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a beginner in Java so I went with the classic, albeit maybe not that efficient approach of hammering it down in for loops

So this is what I got:

```
String splitUpperCase(String input){
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    String output = ""; 
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        char[] ch = words[i].toCharArray();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < ch.length; ii++){
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch[ii]) || Character.isTitleCase(ch[ii])){
                output = output + words[i] + " ";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
```

And the output is:

```
DOCTOR Foo Bar
```